# Change which RDS database an AWS EB environment uses

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

How can I change which RDS database my EB environment uses? I.e. where are the settings that specify this?

I have cloned an environment and want to change the database it uses to an existing RDS database rather than the one that was created when the environment was cloned.

Comment: Are you referring to Elastic Beanstalk environments? Your question is not very clear.

Comment: Is your environment using EB? In that case you can set in the environment variables (under: configuration > software configuration) in case you are reading them.

Comment: Yes I am using EB. I can see where to see the RDS configuration for the environment but I can't see where I can edit it. Can you point me in the right direction.

Comment: Not sure why people are downvoting you as this is a real problem. If you create an EB with an RDS, the RDS info gets listed under DATA TIER and there is no way to update it or change it. The URL everyone keeps linking does not deal with this scenario., rather goes into how to add an RDS to an EB that wasn't created with one.

Answer (score 4):

Is your environment using EB?

In that case you can set in the environment variables:

[image]

in case you are reading them.

Maybe that might be useful:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.RDS.html?console_help=true

**Scroll down to see how to use an existing RDS instance after open your specific language page

Comment: I have a configuration section headed RDS which shows the database connection but this is not listed as per your screen dump in the Software Configuration.

Comment: Sorry tough, is that helpful: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.RDS.html?console_help=true 
If you choose your language, there is a pretty straightforward description about how to proceed in each case. **PS: scroll down the page to see how to use an existing RDS instance