# Where can the RDS_DB_NAME setting for an Elastic Beanstalk environment be changed

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I have Python code installed in an AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment. This code uses RDS_DB_NAME (and other related environment variables) in the setttings.py file. E.g.

```js
DATABASES = {}
try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError, e:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'OPTIONS': {
                "init_command": "SET foreign_key_checks = 0;",
            },
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
            'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
            'PASSWORD': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
            'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
            'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
     
        }
    }
```

I want to change within the Elastic Beanstalk dashboard where these environment variable point. I.e I want them to point to a different existing RDS database.

Can anyone tell me where in the dashboard these can be changed?

Comment: Is this not a duplicate of your previous post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344579/change-which-rds-database-an-aws-eb-environment-uses

Comment: It is similar but it specifically addresses whether or not it is possible to change the environment variables within AWS. The other question was broader.

Answer (score 10):

IU assume you've NOT asked beanstalk to create the RDS for you, which you shouldn't have due to lack of flexibility. If you open the beanstalk console, navigate to your environment => configuration => software configuration => environment properties. There you can set `RDS_DB_NAME` and other environment vars.
This works perfectly for me.

Comment: Thanks Tal. The environment properties is empty so I can't see where the RDS_DB_NAME is set? I could add an RDS_DB_NAME environment variable but how can I be sure it will override the one that is clearly set somewhere else?

Comment: Did you create the db yourself of let beanstalk do it? anyway, just override it.

Comment: Hi @BillNoble - did you get to the bottom of this? I have a similar issue.